# CSS hide/show effect works on Firefox but not on Chrome/Safari

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, hide, show

I'm working on a CSS hide/show effect. It works fine on Firefox. You click on it, the `Hello World` text appears. Then you click again, and it disappears.

But on Chrome/Safari, you have to click **and hold** the button to make it appear.

How can I make it work properly on Chrome/Safari like it does on Firefox?

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2jhaaqft/).

HTML:

```
<div class="formatting_show" id="formatting_show"></div>

<span id="formatting_content"> Hello World </span>
```

CSS:

```
#formatting_show {
    cursor: pointer; 
    cursor: hand;
    float: right;
    font-size: 30px;
    height: 15px;
    text-align: right;
    width: 74px;
    color: #000;
}

#formatting_content {
    display: block;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-out;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-out;
    opacity: 0; 
    height: 0;
    font-size: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#formatting_show:before {
    content: "Formatting «"
}
#formatting_show:active.formatting_show:before {
    content: "Formatting »"
}
#formatting_show:active ~ span#formatting_content {
    font-size: 30px;
    height: 70px;
    opacity: 1;
}

#formatting_content {
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: I guess the `:active` is implemented differently in different browsers

Comment: @Huangism Do you know how to adjust it to make it work universally? If you do, please provide a fiddle for testing.

Comment: I would use js for this kind of click behaviour, in webkit browsers, the active state is only added if you hold the mouse button down on the item. I don't think it is doable using css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with @Huangism who wrote in a comment, that this isn't possible with the `:active` pseudo class. However, you could use a **HTML checkbox**, a **label** for that checkbox and the [**general sibling selector**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors) in CSS ([see also](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/g/general-sibling/)).

This is all the HTML code:

```html
<input  id="formatting_show" type="checkbox" />
<label for="formatting_show">Formatting</label>

<div class="formatting_content">Hello World</div>
```

And the complete CSS code:

```css
#formatting_show {
    display: none;
}
.formatting_content {
    display: none;
}
#formatting_show:checked ~ .formatting_content {
    display: block;
}
```

You can take a look at [a running example](http://jsfiddle.net/hj1uL2fh/).

Comment: Nice idea! Instead of moving the checkbox out of the viewport you can also use `display: none;` or `visibility: hidden;` to hide it.

Comment: @Jay, thanks for your suggestion; I've updated my answer. Henrik I'm glad you like it!